# ImageRenderer not loading WebImage in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, sdwebimage, ios16

I am trying to capture a snapshot of a view. Everything is working fine but when I try to load an image from a URL using the SDWebImageView library, it's simply not loading the image.

This is my code:

```
@MainActor func render() {
    let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: card())
    renderer.scale = displayScale
    if let uiImage = renderer.uiImage {
        renderedImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}
```

This is how I am sharing image

```
ShareLink("Export", item: renderedImage, preview: SharePreview(Text("Share Resolution image"), image: renderedImage))
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: it's not a static view, you cannot use ImageRenderer in this way, You should use @StateObject private var renderer: ImageRenderer<ContentView>, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer.